# How to compare date from table with variable using db_query?

Tags: database

I am trying to retrieve all records from a specific date, given the variable `$date`. I am using db_select and ->condition (due to a lot of joins).

I like to do something like:

```
->condition("`tableName`.`field_date_value` )", $date)
```

That doesn't return anything. Perhaps due to different time because `field_date_value` has a time set and $date hasn't. I looked into using a SQL functions like `DATEDIFF`, but it doesn't work for me.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to insure that the format of your `$date` variable is formatted exactly the same as the format of the date value in your database (`field_date_value`). For example, if your database is storing its date values in `unixtime`, then your `$date` variable needs to be unixtime. If your `field_date_value` field is storing `mm:dd:yy hh:mm:ss`, then your `$date` variable needs to reflect this same format accordingly. Refer to [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to formate your `$date` variable the appropriate way.

Once you've formatted your `$date` variable to the same formate of your sql data, you can run a condition method like this:

```
->condition("tablename.field_date_value", $date, ">=")
```

This will query for everything equal to or greater than the specified `$date` value.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your `$date` variable is set, you might want to try MySQL function [curdate()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate). It returns only the date of a datetime column which can then be compared.